name of a science-fiction cyborg movie
A movie from the 80s or 90s where a team of soldiers are out hunting a rogue cyborg
american-made movie set out mostly in a desert / mountain area
However the cyborg is better and starts killing them off and the soldiers find out THEY are also cyborgs and didn't realize it till they get killed and show mechanical stuff inside them
The movie ended with the last guy and girl soldier killing the rogue and preferring not finding out if they are themselves cyborgs or not as well.

Please try to add anything that may help identification. What country was it likely from? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

Searched tirelessly for this movie a few weeks back and just couldn't find it anywhere then I noticed it was starring the dude from "I Come In Peace". I believe the movie you are looking for is called "Digital Man" starring Matthias Hues.

An out-of-control robot is inadvertently set loose in a small community, and a crack squad of soldiers are sent to hunt it down. Gradually, the members of the squad begin to suspect that some of them are robots.





Thank you for assisting the community. Can you please explain more about why this movie is the answer? Sharing links or clips is usually helpful.

yep thasts the one, thanks guys

I'm thinking it's Universal Soldier from 1992 starring Jean Claude Van Damme and Dolph Lundgren.

They were Army Special Forces guys in Vietnam who killed each other when Dolph went insane. Decades later, they are revived as scientifically engineered super-soldiers:

Deveraux and Scott are revived without memories of their previous
  lives and are selected for the "Universal Soldier" program, an elite
  counter terrorism unit, and are deployed via an Aero Spacelines Mini
  Guppy to the Hoover Dam to resolve a hostage situation... In the
  mobile command center, it is revealed that the UniSols are genetically
  augmented soldiers with enhanced healing abilities and superior
  strength, but also have a tendency to overheat and shut down.

Jean Claude and the still-insane Dolph battle it out for the rest of the movie, much of which takes place in the desert. The ending also matches OP's description.
